# Hard drive disk seems to "move" its weight when running

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life

I have an external box for hard drives and plugged a broken hard disk to it. Then I turned it on and took it in hand.

Now, if I gently tilt and turn the box on its axis, the weight seems to "go" in different directions, similarly to what happens if I put an heavy ball in a little box and move it around.

Knowing that inside the hard disk there are no moving parts except for the spinning metal disks, what could cause this behaviour?

By the way: don't do that if you care about the data inside, you might end up scratching disks surfaces and losing everything :)

Comment: Is it acting like a gyroscope?

Comment: It can be, I'm not entirely sure. That's why I came here asking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hard drive platters are relatively heavy, and spin at a very high speed (7200 rpm for most hard drives, and even 10000 rpm or more for high-performance drives), the hard drive becomes one big gyroscope.

If you've ever seen a [gyroscope toy](http://www.tedcotoys.com/c/gyroscopes), you've observed gyroscopic precession firsthand.  When you turn your hard drive along any axis other than the axis of rotation, you're effectively [*inducing* the precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession#Torque-induced) of the gyroscope. That is, when you apply a torque that changes the direction of the spin axis, the gyroscope responds as if that torque was applied at an offset of 90 degrees in the direction of rotation.